# Snapping UISlider to nearest array value

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

I have a question using Swift 2 on an iOS 9 project.

I've created an array for a UISlider, which is working. However, the slider doesn't 'snap' to the array values, it can sit in between them and be numbers in between the array values. As I'm doing some calculations off of the values, it's messing up my maths. Is there any way to make the sliver value snap to the nearest array value?

Below is my code.

```
let fpsArray = ["23.98", "24", "25","29.97","30","50","59.94","60"]
let angleArray = ["11.25","15","22.5","30","37.5","45","60","72","75","90","108","120","144","150","172.8","180","216","270","324","360"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@IBAction func fpsLabelChange(sender: UISlider) {


    let currentValue = fpsArray[Int(sender.value)]
    fpsLabel.text = "\(currentValue)"

}

@IBAction func angleLabelChange(sender: UISlider) {


    let anglecurrentValue = angleArray[Int(sender.value)]
    angleLabel.text = "\(anglecurrentValue)"

}

@IBAction func changeSpeedLabel(sender: AnyObject) {

    //maths
    let framespersecond = fpsSlider.value
    let shutterangle = angleSlider.value
    let shutterspeed = (framespersecond * 360) / (shutterangle)
    speedLabel.text = "1/\(shutterspeed)"
```

Comment: Just use the slider to slide the array index (0,1,2,3,4,5,6..) and just display the element at that index

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Slider from 0 to array.count-1 step 1

Comment: If they are related to each other consider using 2D array

Comment: @LeoDabus I think the _snap_ effect is the key functionality he wants.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, from Apple [Document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UISlider_Class/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006798-CH3-SW19)

> A `UISlider` object is a visual control used to select a single value from a **continuous** range of values.

And to achieve similar visual arrangement, rather than using a `UIPickerView` (you can still use if you want), according to another Apple [Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISlider.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISlider)

> You should use a stepper instead of a slider when you want to give users very precise control over the value of an element. For more information, see [Steppers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStepper_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIStepper).

If you do consider `UIStepper`, you can use the stepper value for index of your array, and display corresponding value in your `fpsArray` and `angleArray` to your labels.

**Or**

To use `UISlider`, you still need to do some *horrible* math to determine which value it is close to. As your array is *not* an arithmetic sequence, it will be hard to design a good way to reflect the different number differences.

By continuously tracking the value of `UISlider`, you can set the value of the slider and text at the same time after you found out the closest value available.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I ended up going with a stepper

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
let currentValue = fpsArray[Int(floor(sender.value+0.5))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help. I ended up making the text label into a int, which calls from the array and uses the stepper to move through the array.

```
    let a:Int? = Int(fpsLabel.text!)
    let b:Int? = Int(angleLabel.text!)
    let shutterspeed = (a! * 360) / b!
    speedLabel.text = "1/\(shutterspeed)"
```